# matlab: eliminate elements from array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, grouping

I have quite big array. To make things simple lets simplify it to:

```
A = [1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5];
```

So, there is a group of 1's (4 elements), 2's (2 elements), 3's (4 elements), 4's (2 elements) and 5's (8 elements). Now, I want to keep only columns, which belong to group of 3 or more elements. So it will be like:

```
B = [1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5];
```

I was doing it using *for* loop, scanning separately 1's, 2's, 3's and so on, but its extremely slow with big arrays... 
Thanks for any suggestions how to do it in more efficient way :)
Art.

Comment: Can you be sure that the array is always sorted? Does it contain only integers? Is the step between values always 1?

Comment: 1) Yes, the array is always sorted. But note, that I've shown only the first row of my array. There are other values, but they are not taken into account since only this first row is used for elimination (but of course, the whole column will be deleted if criteria are not met). 2) In my case, only integers. 3) No, step could be different than 1.

Comment: Thanks to all for fantastic solutions, you are wonderful! I have to go and test them now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my two-liner

```
counts = accumarray(A', 1);
B = A(ismember(A, find(counts>=3)));
```

accumarray is used to count the individual members of A. find extracts the ones that meet your '3 or more elements' criterion. Finally, ismember tells you where they are in A. Note that A needs not be sorted. Of course, accumarray only works for integer values in A.

Comment: +1: I believe that this won't work with non-integers, though.

Answer (score 8):

#### A general approach

If your vector is not necessarily sorted, then you need to run to count the number of occurrences of each element in the vector. You have [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) just for that:

```
elem = unique(A);
counts = histc(A, elem);
B = A;
B(ismember(A, elem(counts < 3))) = []
```

The last line picks the elements that have less than 3 occurrences and deletes them.

#### An approach for a grouped vector

If your vector is "semi-sorted", that is if similar elements in the vector are grouped together (as in your example), you can speed things up a little by doing the following:

```
start_idx = find(diff([0, A]))
counts = diff([start_idx, numel(A) + 1]);
B = A;
B(ismember(A, A(start_idx(counts < 3)))) = []
```

Again, note that the vector need not to be entirely sorted, just that similar elements are adjacent to each other.

Comment: Just a general remark: Doesn't this solution only work if A consists of integer values? (Yes, I know, OP did not specify whether A can also hold non-integers). However, nice solution anyway...

Comment: @H.Muster Thanks for pointing that out. I improved it to work for non-integer values as well :)

Comment: +1 Your approach works for non-integers in A, but at the cost of reading A one additional time :) trade-off..

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is called [run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_length).

There is software for this in Matlab on the FileExchange. Or you can do it directly as follows:

```
len = diff([ 0 find(A(1:end-1) ~= A(2:end)) length(A) ]);
val = A(logical([ A(1:end-1) ~= A(2:end) 1 ]));
```

Once you have your run-length encoding you can remove elements based on the length. i.e.

```
idx = (len>=3)
len = len(idx);
val = val(idx);
```

And then decode to get the array you want:

```
i = cumsum(len);
j = zeros(1, i(end));
j(i(1:end-1)+1) = 1; 
j(1) = 1; 
B = val(cumsum(j));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it using matlab built-ins.

```
% Set up
A=[1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 5];
threshold=2;

% Get the unique elements of the array
uniqueElements=unique(A);

% Count haw many times each unique element occurs
counts=histc(A,uniqueElements);

% Write which elements should be kept
toKeep=uniqueElements(counts>threshold);

% Make a logical index
indexer=false(size(A));
for i=1:length(toKeep)
    % For every unique element we want to keep select the indices in A that
    % are equal
    indexer=indexer|(toKeep(i)==A);
end

% Apply index
B=A(indexer);
```

Comment: This won't work if there are separate groups of the same element.

Comment: @robince I wasn't quite sure from the question, if that's what the OP wants, but in that case disregard my answer. My method doesn't care about order.